# Sort Excel table sheets with FME

Tags: fme-form, excel, sorting

I have 4 feature types and writing to a single xls file using FME. Each feature type has its own worksheet.

How can I sort the worksheets with FME before creating the xls-file?

I use FME 2012 SP3

Comment: I use a Oracle Database

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [Sorter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/sorter.htm)?

> Each attribute can be sorted alphabetically or numerically and can be
>   sorted either in ascending or descending order. By default, the sort
>   direction is in ascending order. Alphabetic ordering will sort
>   according to ASCII ordering rules.

After sorting, you can write to multiple worksheets in an excel file [or perform other types of excel manipulation.](https://blog.safe.com/2013/10/tale-magical-transformation-excel-spreadsheet/)

> On the writing side, multiple sheets are also supported. In fact, a
>   feature type fan-out will automatically filter your data into a series
>   of sheets by type.

Comment: I found a way by myself. Before I write the xls-file I sort the Data with the AttributeFilter. So I can sort by the attribute I want. Thanks for the quick answer MaryBeth! The Question can be closed